# React return statement turns into single line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Suppose that I am working in **Visual Studio Code** and I have a simple functional component (created with **rfce** snippet) and it is something like this:

```
import React from 'react'

function Sidebar() {
    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Sidebar
```

When I save the code (I have format on save enabled on **prettier**) it turns into a single line return statement like this:

```
import React from 'react';

function Sidebar() {
    return <div></div>;
}

export default Sidebar;
```

It's pretty annoying, does anyone know how turn that off?

Comment: Sorrry for that. I thought that saying rfce code snippet and format on save was enough. My bad, I just edited the question with that info.

Comment: Don't mind the downvotes. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15611 have a read here

Answer (score 0):

Prettier doesn't have [an option](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) for that, and [it won't get one](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html).

If an expression fits on a single line, then prettier will put it on a single line.

If you want Prettier's formatting then you have to accept its opinions about what is good.